# List index out of range error in the code

Tags: python

I have the following piece of code.

```
result = "1/1/2010|1/2/2111"
request = "1/1/1.3.4.5.6/1/1/127.0.0.1"

replylist = result.split("|")
finalresultlist = [
    f"{i.split('/')[2]}.{j.split('/')[2]}"
        for i in request
        for j in replylist \
        if (i.split("/")[1] == j.split("/")[1])
]

print(finalresultlist)
```

Note: The `f"{i.split('/')[2]}.{j.split('/')[2]}"` concatenates the `"1.3.4.5.6"` with the `"2010"` when there is a match `if (i.split("/")[1] == j.split("/")[1])` based on the value in the index [1] after each of the `result` and `request` strings are split on the `'|'`.

I want to return a new string, which concatenates the 1.3.4.5.6 of `request` with 2010 of `result` to return a list which contains the string: `["1.3.4.5.6.2010"]`

In my current code, I get the error "list out of range". I am unable to resolve this issue.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `request` is a string, and iterating over it (`for i in request`) gives you one character at a time. It looks to me like you're trying to do too many things at once.

Comment: @molbdnilo May you help me to resolve my bug. I want to be able to concatenate the ```1.3.4.5.6``` with the ```2010```.

Comment: It would be great if you could post the stacktrace of the error.

Comment: @GaneshTata I updated the comments with description

Comment: It might help your understanding to convert the list comprehension to a for-loop and avoid using f-strings.

Comment: Please post the full error message including stack trace

Comment: I just get the error, Index out of range on the part of code ``` if (i.split("/")[1] == j.split("/")[1])```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Debugging

As [molbdnilo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/404970/molbdnilo) [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57676910/list-index-out-of-range-error-in-the-code#comment101800983_57676910),

> `request` is a string, and iterating over it (`for i in request`) gives you one character at a time. It looks to me like you're trying to do too many things at once.

And if we look at the full error message including stack trace, we see a suggestion of that:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/wjandrea/test.py", line 7, in <module>
    for i in request
  File "/home/wjandrea/test.py", line 9, in <listcomp>
    if (i.split("/")[1] == j.split("/")[1])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Rearranging the code points to `i.split("/")[1]` being the problem.

#### Solution

Remove `for i in request` entirely, and substitute `request` for `i`.

```
finalresultlist = [
    f"{request.split('/')[2]}.{j.split('/')[2]}"
    for j in replylist
    if request.split("/")[1] == j.split("/")[1]
]
```

**Output**: `['1.3.4.5.6.2010']`

Then there are some other improvements we could make, like better variable names and moving stuff out of the list comprehension.

```
replies = [i.split('/') for i in result.split("|")]
request_list = request.split('/')

final_result_list = [
    f"{request_list[2]}.{reply[2]}"
    for reply in replies
    if request_list[1] == reply[1]
]

print(final_result_list)
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok let's take baby steps.

```
result = "1/1/2010|1/2/2111"
result = result.split("|")
```

Now `result` is `['1/1/2010', '1/2/2111']`

```
request = "1/1/1.3.4.5.6/1/1/127.0.0.1"
request = request.split("/")
```

Now `request` is `['1', '1', '1.2.3.4.5.6', '1', '1', '127.0.0.1']`
So a simple way to get your desired result would be,

```
finalresult = "{}{}".format(request[2],result.split('/')[2])
```

I'm not sure of your looping logic, however, you should be able to use this code to programmatically generate more strings based on your business logic.